# Usage of Libsvm model

Tags: matlab, model, svm, libsvm, prediction

I've developed a model using Libsvm in Matlab. I've choose best parameters using CV and I obtained the model training the whole dataset. I use normalization to get better results:

```m
 maximum=max(TR)+0.00001;
 minimum=min(TR);

 for i=1:size(TR,2)
             training(1:size(TR,1),i)=double(TR(1:size(TR,1),i)-maximum(i))/(maximum(i)-minimum(i));
 end
```

Now how can I use directly my model to obtain classification for new data? I mean for records that haven't class label. Do I have to manually build functions from model information?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `libsvmtrain` to train on your training data? If so, there is an output argument that you can use to classify test/future data. Then pass that output structure to `svmpredict` along with test data.

Comment: Yes I'm using `svmtrain` to train data. I think that the output argument you're saying it's the model. But if I want to use  `svmpredict` shouldn't have labelled data? If I have an unclassified new record do I have to label it with a random class and call `svmpredict` ?

Comment: Yes it's the model. And yes, if you don't have the label just pass in any random value - that argument is just to calculate accuracy anyway (in case the labels are known).